# How do I fix the error $.ui.dialog.defaults is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have one error on my page and it is stopping some other javascript from functioning correctly:

```
$.ui.dialog.defaults is undefined
      $.ui.dialog.defaults.bgiframe = true;
```

[image: error]

What steps can I take to fix this error?

I have this in the head

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/demo/system/ext/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/demo/system/ext/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You will need to add more detail. Can you show how you are embedding jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: Included in the head of the page as above....Is it an issue with where I have jquery/jquery-ui ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version of jQuery UI are you using? The defaults were moved from `$.ui.dialog.defaults` to `$.ui.dialog.prototype.options` in version 1.8:

> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Upgrade_Guide_18#Properties_moved_from_.24.ui.foo_to_.24.ui.foo.prototype

The best way (and probably the only sane way) to fix things is to go through all your code and change all your `$.ui.X.defaults` references to `$.ui.X.prototype.defaults` where **X** is the jQuery-UI widget in question. A review of the Upgrade Guide for other possible issues would be a good idea too.

Comment: Just a further point, what is the best way to fix it? Go through my site and update all the references, I need jquery-ui > version 1.8

Comment: You'll have to go through and fix the `.defaults` references, I updated my answer to cover this (which I should have included in the first place.